# Data Driven protractor spec

Tags: jasmine, protractor

Is there a way to execute protractor spec in new browser for different customers.

The list of customers will come from a file.

spec file is "testOverview.spec.js", want this spec to be executed for each customer, preferably in parallel if possible

For Each Customer

1) Open New Browser
 2) Login
 3) Check the Value
 4) done (clear everything so that next customer starts fresh(need to login))

Answer (score 0):

You can create a JS file with the data in the following format:

```
var dataPage = {
companyDetails : [
{company : 'detail'},
{company : 'detail'},
{company : 'detail'},
{company : 'detail'}
]
};
```

Import the file in your test file and run your test for each company.
Test will execute one by one and not in parallel using this method.

Comment: the first part is clear, i can read the values from file, its the second part that i am not sure how to achieve, is that a loop, where this loop has be written etc(any samples will be appreciated)......

Comment: You can copy the **companyDetails** in an object in your test file like following:  

    var companies = companyDetails.company;
    for(var i=0; i< companies.length; i++){
      // do something with each of your company
    }

Answer (score 0):

You may write a "it" block for this and iterate it over with multiple sets of data of customer like below:

```
var customersData = testConfig.testArray;
  customersData.map(function(customers) {
        it('write your test here', function() {
          console.log('CustomerName: ', customers.customerName);
         });
 });
```